# I'm trying to get a table to change the text of the rows with a function

Tags: javascript, html-table

So basically, I want to have a little setup where I can put the name of a vegetable in the input and have all of the info I need autofill into the adjacent rows, so far I've got this.. which may be a total mess I'm not sure. In the `insertText` function I had some sample text instead of the `whichVeggie` function which worked on the first row at least. No one has to lay out any code for me to copy paste or anything, but should the `insertText` and `whichVeggie` be one function? I'm just lost any help would be appreciated.

```js
function addField(n) {
  var tr = n.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("tbl").appendChild(tr);
}

function insertText(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById("sowTime").innerHTML = whichVeggie();
    document.getElementById("harvestTime").innerHTML = whichVeggie();
  }
}

function whichVeggie() {
  var textEntered = document.getElementById("plantNameEntered").innerHTML;
  var sowTime = getElementById("sowTime").innerHTML;
  var harvestTime = getElementById("harvestTime").innerHTML;

  if (textEntered == "tomato") {
    sowTime = "100 days";
    harvestTime = "200 days";
  }
  return sowTime && harvestTime;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>Plant Planning Guide</title>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+Unicase:wght@300&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <h2>When to sow, plant outdoors and harvest in zone 7a</h2>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="tbl" style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Plant Name</th>
      <th>Time to Sow indoors</th>
      <th>Time Until Harvest</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input
          id="plantNameEntered"
          type="text"
          name="plantName"
          placeholder="Enter Name..."
          onkeypress="insertText(event);"
        />
      </td>
      <td type="text" id="sowTime"></td>
      <td type="text" id="harvestTime"></td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="submit"
          class="button"
          value="Add another plant"
          onclick="addField(this);"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I am seeing multiple issue in you JS code. 1) In whichVeggie(), you need to write document.getElementById(). 2) to get value of textEntered, you need value instead of innerHTML.3) you can't return multiple values in javascript with val1 && val2, you need [val1,val2] to returnt the value. Tried and tested these correction and your code will be working. and your question's answer: Its ok to have different function to get veggies value.

Comment: Do you plan on only have 1 row? If not, then you'll need to change the IDs you're using. There is no "type=text" attribute for TD. The whichVeggie function will get messy very quickly as you add additional vegetables, I suggest using arrays to store the values.  The way you're returning values in whichVeggie will cause issues if you change the value in the first field ever, as the logical AND will always return the first value now they're both filled.

Comment: Ah! @Dhara you're an angel!!

Comment: @Phaelaxz, I agree, I was thinking of doing arrays for all the info. Just trying to get things functioning a little first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should the insertText and whichVeggie be one function?

It is totally fine to have different function to get veggie.
I am not going to write whole correct code as you prefer so.

Here are few corrections you required in your JS:

1. syntax error: to get a DOM,such as
   `document.getElementById("sowTime").innerHTML;`
2. to get value, need to use `value` instead of **innerHTML**
3. To return multiple value in function, need to use array like return [val1, val2] and extract values when you need it like `whichVeggie()[0]`

Voila!!!

(I post it in solution block as well so it would help others quickly rather than going in every comments : Just for better reachability )

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you didn't need code, but I think seeing this might help you.

```
// Create an object to act as an associative array
var vegetables = [];
vegetables['tomato'] = ['100 days', '200 days'];
vegetables['corn']   = ['120 days', '250 days'];
```

We drop the whichVeggie() function in place of the following. No worries about looking up IDs

```
function insertText(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // e.target will point to the input field that triggered this event
        // .value will retrieve the text from that field
        // Retrieve the vegetable data from the object
        v = vegetables[e.target.value];
        
        // Make sure it found a match in the object
        if (typeof v !== 'undefined'){
            // Remember e.target is the input element. The first parent of 
            // it will be TD (the cell). The parent of that TD will give us the TR (table row)
            // children then give us an array of all TDs in that row.
            var c = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children;
            
            // c[1] references the 2nd TD in the row, c[2] is the 3rd TD
            // v[0] and v[1] reference the two values assigned to the specified vegetable above
            c[1].innerHTML = v[0];
            c[2].innerHTML = v[1];
        
        }
    }
}
```